# How to add multiple renderer in Ext JS Grid Columns

Tags: extjs4

I have Ext JS Grid in which there is one numeric column on which I would like to add two type of renderer
1.colorRenderer: this renderer will decide whether to show numeric value in red or green based on value is less thn zero or greater thn zero
2. formatRenderer: this renderer is to format numeric value upto 2 decimal

adding something like in columns isn't working

renderer: colorRenderer, formatRenderer

one way i can write another ClubbedRenderer and inside that call both these renderer but that will make it cause unscalable solution and it need to get all permutation combination if new renderer comes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with this:

```
renderer: function( aValue, aMeta, aRecord )
{
    aMeta.style = aValue >= 0 ? "color: #00FF00;" : "color: #FF0000;";
    return Ext.util.Format.number( aValue, '0.00' );
}
```

See a working [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Izhaki/9XR7x/1/).

Comment: thanks for answer. However, I'm interested to know how render1, render2, render3 .... can be applied to renderer property... something like auto chain.

Comment: Do you mean in the config? So `renderer: { renderer1, renderer2 }`?

Comment: yes something like this .. ok great so u mean renderer: {renderer1, renderer2} will work if supplied in config.

Comment: No it wouldn't because renderer is not expecting an array of renderers, but you can write your own code to do so.